# FastApi - How to pass get_db dependency in Custom Middleware dispatch function?

Tags: python, database, fastapi, middleware

I have a fastapi application and I want to do some db queries inside dispatch function of Custom Middleware function. I am not sure how to pass db in dispatch function.

```
class MyMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):

    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):

        access_token = request.headers.get("access-token")
        if not access_token:
            return JSONResponse(status_code=401, content={"errors": str("access_token not found")})
        # some db query

        response = await call_next(request)
        return response
```

```
class MyMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):

    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):

        access_token = request.headers.get("access-token")
        if not access_token:
            return JSONResponse(status_code=401, content={"errors": str("access_token not found")})
        # some db query

        response = await call_next(request)
        return response
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.